# Найти сумму всех максимальных по модулю элементов в нечетных строках матрицы Python

Tags: python, матрицы

Прочесть действительную матрицу размером n*n. Найти сумму всех максимальных по модулю элементов в нечетных (по индексу, начиная от 1) строках

Я попыталась, но что-то не то.. Как исправить?

```
n = int(input("n="))
a=[]
sum=0
for i in range(n):
    a.append(list(map(int,input().split())))
b=list(map(lambda x: 0, range(n)))
if n <= 2:
    if a[i+1][j+1] > a[i+1][j]:
        print(a[i+1][j+1])
    else:
        if a[i+1][j+1] < a[i+1][j]:
            print(a[i+1][j])
else:
    for j in range(1,n,2):
        m=0
        for i in range(0,n):
            if abs(m) < abs(a[i][j]):
                m=abs(a[i][j])
        sum += m
    print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. зачем вам

   ```
    b=list(map(lambda x: 0, range(n)))`
   ```

, если вы ее нигде не используете?

2. `sum=0`, вообще-то `sum` - это функция стандартная, не стоит переменные называть такими же именами
3. `int(input("n="))` - я надеюсь вы просто код плохо скопировали (исправил) и надо было

   ```
    n = int(input("n="))
   ```
4. `if n <= 2:` - зачем эта проверка? код универсальный и так и должен работать при любых `n`
5. у вас `m` всегда неотрицательный

   ```
    if abs(m) < abs(a[i][j]):
        m=abs(a[i][j])
   ```

так что проверку можно было бы сделать и так:

```
    if m < abs(a[i][j]):
        m=abs(a[i][j])
```

6. `range(0,n)` можно просто как `range(n)`

**P.S.**

приведённый код можно было бы сделать таким:

```
n = int(input("n="))
a = [list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(n)]

res = sum(max(a[i], key=abs) for i in range(1, n, 2))

print(res)
```

если строки со столбцами поменять надо, то

```
a = list(zip(*[list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(n)]))
```

Comment: исправила всё, но все еще считает не правильно, и не уверенна что именно строки через 1

Comment: ну у вас строки и столбцы просто могут быть перепутаны - замените везде `a[i][j]` на `a[j][i]` и посмотрите результат

Comment: if n <= 2 это вообще убрать надо?

Comment: ааа оно считает четные, как сделать наоборот?

Comment: конечно - вы и так с 1 строкой получите ответ 0, а с 2 - будет обработана строка 1, в только учтите, что нумерация то у вас с 0 идет, а в жизни - с 1, поэтому вам возможно надо чётные строки искать, а не нечетные

Comment: `range(0,n,2):` - начните просто с 0 строки